# Spring Batch ItemReadListener is never called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am learning Spring batch. I have a small basic job which will read data from flat file and write it to the database and sends the notification. The job works fine.
Now I wanted to use ItemReadListener to learn how it works, so I added it to my job.
But when I run the job the ItemReadListener is never called
Below is the code for my ItemListener

```
public class CustomItemReadListener implements ItemReadListener {
  @Override
  public void beforeRead() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Before Read");
  }

  @Override
  public void afterRead(Object o) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("afterRead");
    System.out.println(o.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public void onReadError(Exception e) throws Exception {

  }
}
```

My job defintion is below

```
 <job id="loaddataToDatabase" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="loadDataStep">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <chunk commit-interval="100" reader="feedItemReader" writer="feedItemWriter">
      <listeners>
        <listener ref="customItemReadListener">
        </listener>
      </listeners>
      </chunk>
    </tasklet>
    <next on="FAILED" to="sendFileLoadNotification"/>

    <next on="*" to="sendFileLoadNotification"/>

  </step>
  </job>

  <bean id="customItemReadListener" class="com.listeners.CustomItemReadListener" scope="step"/>
```

The job runs successfully, but the ItemReadListener is never called. Is my job config correct or am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that at least one item is read? Or listener#onReadError() is called due to and error?

Comment: Hi, I can see the records are read and written to the database but the listener is never called

Comment: May you remove scope to listener and re-run the job? The scope seems pretty useless in this case. I can't debug, so if you don't found and nobody answer your question, you may set SB log to debug level and read the log or debug the flow yourself

Comment: Have you tried to move the `listeners` outside the `<chunk>` element and put it under `<tasklet>` (aka next to `<chunk>`)?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the listeners just after the chunk. It works for me with this config:

```
@Bean
    public Step kycCreationStep() {
        log.debug("start kycCreationStep ...");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("kycCreationStep").<IndividualImport, IndividualImport>chunk(initChunkSize).listener(new StepItemReadListener())
                .reader(kycCreationReader(null, null, null)).processor(kycCreationProcessor())
                .writer(kycCreationWriter(null)).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomItemReadListener implements ItemReadListener {
    @Override
    @BeforeRead
    public void beforeRead() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Before Read");
    }

    @Override
    @AfterRead
    public void afterRead(Object o) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterRead");
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }

    @Override
    @OnReadError
    public void onReadError(Exception e) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

you need to add the annotation, because this method `public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> listener(Object listener)` check if the annotation exist.